# javascript: how to set window object parameters after loading

Tags: javascript, parameters, window, onload

When users navigate to my website, I want to resize window and remove scrollbar, title bar, address bar etc on the first window. This is for intranet web application. Idea is to show a resized small login window similar to Evernote desktop application login window. In other words, I need to do this - 
Window.open("login.aspx", "_self", "height=250, width= 500, location=0, menubar=0, resizable=0, scrollbars=0, status=0, titlebar=0, toolbar=0");
But I need to do it on the same window, the first window that user navigates to. Is it possible using javascript?
I know that I can use moveTo and resizeTo function to position and resize the window. How to remove address bar, location bar, menu bar, title bar, status bar?  **Browser is IE6 & IE8 only.** I don't need to support other browsers.

Comment: I don't think you can on the original window (as opposed to a child window). And, people with multiple tabs and just regular folks with be very angry with you if you start resizing and moving around their browser window.

Comment: This is intranet application. We plan to create a shortcut on user's desktop, which opens in to a resized login window. So the tab issue won't be there.

Answer (score 0):

in the cureent window do:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
window.onload = function() {
  window.resizeTo(200,300);
}
</script>
```

Try it, enter this into the location bar of your browser: javascript:window.resizeTo(200,300);

Beware: some browsers offer the user options to suppress such browser features (FF for example).